# Issue with Dropdown design when validating with jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I'm validating dropdown using jquery validator, using below code, i tried to reproduce the same but the form is disappearing after clicking on submit button, the issue i' m facing is validation is proper but there is label added  that takes extra spaces as shown in the image below with the help of arrow, i want to remove that extra white space.I have given outline to fields if any error is there.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
span.error{
    outline: 1px solid red;

}

.parent-error {
    outline:1px solid red;
    background:red;
}

.input-validation-error {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<form action="#" id="register-form">
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
<label for="city">City</label>                          
<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
<option value="Alld">Alld</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"  class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>

<script>
    (function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
  jQuery.validator.messages.required = '';


        jQuery("form#register-form").validate({
            ignore:'input[type=hidden]',
            rules:
            {

                state: { required: true },

            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                var elem = jQuery(element);

                if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                    element = jQuery("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent(); 
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                } 
                else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                var elem = jQuery(element); 
                if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                    jQuery("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent().addClass(errorClass); 
                } 
                else if(elem.is(':checkbox'))
                {
                    elem.addClass("parent-error"); 

                }
                else {
                    elem.addClass('input-validation-error');
                }
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {

                var elem = jQuery(element);
                if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                    jQuery("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent().removeClass(errorClass);
                }
                else if(elem.is(':checkbox'))
                {
                    elem.removeClass("parent-error"); 

                }
                else {
                    elem.removeClass('input-validation-error');
                }
            }, 
            success: function (label, element) {
                //jQuery(element).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });


        jQuery('select').on("change", function (e) {
            jQuery(this).valid()
        }); 
    })( jQuery );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
    jQuery.validator.messages.required = '';


    jQuery("form#register").validate({
        ignore:'input[type=hidden]',
        rules:
        {
            .....
        },messages:{
            .....
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var elem = jQuery(element);
            if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                element = jQuery("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent(); 
                error.insertAfter(element);
            } 
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            var elem = jQuery(element); 
            if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                jQuery("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent().addClass(errorClass); 
            } 
            else if(elem.is(':checkbox'))
            {
                elem.addClass("parent-error"); 

            }
            else {
                elem.addClass('input-validation-error');
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            var elem = jQuery(element);
            if (elem.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
                jQuery("#select2-" + elem.attr("id") + "-container").parent().removeClass(errorClass);
            }
            else if(elem.is(':checkbox'))
            {
                elem.removeClass("parent-error"); 

            }
            else {
                elem.removeClass('input-validation-error');
            }
        }, 
        success: function (label, element) {

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });


    jQuery('select').on("change", function (e) {
        jQuery(this).valid()
    });
```

When there is any error then a space is shown between the dropdown and dropdown items, like in image:

[image]

This is my view source of the design that is being rendered
[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with relevant frameworks, plugins, CSS and HTML

Comment: "Issue with Dropdown design" - and what's the issue?  You've explained nothing in your posting.  What is it you want it to do?  Please elaborate.

Comment: @Sparky: I have added more info about the issue in my question, i'm getting one issue as you can see in the image with the helpof arrow there  are extra space when any validation error is there, that i i think label but i'm not using label here, because i just colored border of dropdown to red when any error is there, how can i remove that whitespace.

Comment: A screenshot of your DOM is not appreciated.  It cannot be indexed by the SO search engine and it makes helping you more difficult.  You'll have to do some troubleshooting.  Examine your live DOM to see exactly where the extra space is being inserted and compare that to what your `errorPlacement` function is doing.